# Как писать наиболее читабельный код в Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

Является ли такая конструкция предпочтительнее, чем if-ы с "{", "}" (см. return)?
И вообще стоит ли делать такую универсальную функцию, которая задает и получает значение, может лучше на две разбить?

```
  Future showNotification(value) async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    return (value == null) ?
      prefs.getBool('notification') ?? false :
      await prefs.setBool('notification', value);
  }
```

Как правильно давать название переменным, функциям, классам?

Без разницы ли, что объявлять в начале? "Пустые" переменные, потом заполненные переменные, потом функции?
Насколько вредно такое скопление виджетов в классе?[image: код]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### 1. `if-else` или тернарная операция

`if-else` классический способ, тернарный функциональный способ. Используется по усмотрению программиста, если при использования тернарного способа выражение становиться длинным, то лучше использовать `if-else`. Иногда бывает, что можно использовать только один из способов.

Разница:

1. В размере записи
2. Нет возможности у тернарного оператора использовать только блок `if`

#### 2. Стоит ли делать такую универсальную функцию

Функции делают для того чтобы не писать одно и тоже много раз, если функция выполняет свою логику без нареканий, то это нормальная функция. В данном примере все хорошо, кроме некоторых но:

1. Лучше вынести этот кусок кода, так как он каждый раз создается, лишняя нагрузка (я бы сделал `singleton`): `SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();`
2. Объявляйте типы для переменных/функций. Это поможет при написании, так как будут показываться подсказки и при дебаге, так как будет видно что происходит.

#### 3. Как правильно давать название переменным, функциям, классам?

[The Clean Code Game](https://cleancodegame.github.io/), и не важно что там C#, самое главное оно объяснит как.

#### 4. Объявление переменных/функций ?

У каждого языка программирования есть Code Style, к которому нужно придерживаться, для Dart это [Effective Dart: Style](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/style), для Flutter это [Style guide for Flutter](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Style-guide-for-Flutter-repo). Там все описано.

#### Итог

Грамотный настроенный `analysis` поможет вам писать более читаемый код, просто добавьте [этот файл](https://gist.github.com/mit-73/027683b120d6ce7a79c1c19a38ac2f1d) в корень вашего проекта, и исправьте ошибки, которые он нашел.

Comment: А что насчёт скопления виджетов в классе страницы? Их лучше вынести в отдельный файл или оставить?

Comment: И почему константы предпочтительнее конструкторов, например здесь: 
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 10)

Comment: Это всё после подключения **analysis**

Comment: @ДаниилЧашков эсли эти виджеты используются только в этом классе, то их нужно оставить в этом классе. Если они используются ещё где-то, их необходимо выносить в отдельный класс (содовая собственный виджет).

Comment: @ДаниилЧашков потому что константана это неизменяемый объект. Она определяется во время компиляции приложения.

Comment: Спасибо большое!)